# applying "tighter" bounds in scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a dataset that I am trying to fit with parameters (a,b,c,d) that are within +/- 5% of the true fitting parameters. However, when I do this with scipy.optimize.curve_fit I `get the error "ValueError: 'x0' is infeasible."` inside the least squares package.

If I relax my bounds, then optimize.curve_fit seems to work as desired. I have also noticed that my parameters that are larger seem to be more flexible in applying bounds (i.e. I can get these to work with tighter constraints, but never below 20%).  The following code is an MWE and has two sets of bounds (variable `B`), one that works and one that returns an error.

```
# %% import modules
import IPython as IP
IP.get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os as os
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.io as sio

plt.close('all')


#%% Load the data
capacity = np.array([1.0,9.896265560165975472e-01,9.854771784232364551e-01,9.823651452282157193e-01,9.797717842323651061e-01,9.776970954356846155e-01,9.751037344398340023e-01,9.735477178423235234e-01,9.714730290456431439e-01,9.699170124481327759e-01,9.683609958506222970e-01,9.668049792531120401e-01,9.652489626556015612e-01,9.636929460580913043e-01,9.621369294605808253e-01,9.610995850622406911e-01,9.595435684647302121e-01,9.585062240663900779e-01,9.574688796680497216e-01,9.559128630705394647e-01,9.548755186721991084e-01,9.538381742738588631e-01,9.528008298755185068e-01,9.517634854771783726e-01,9.507261410788381273e-01,9.496887966804978820e-01,9.486514522821576367e-01,9.476141078838172804e-01,9.460580912863070235e-01,9.450207468879666672e-01,9.439834024896265330e-01,9.429460580912862877e-01,9.419087136929459314e-01,9.408713692946057972e-01,9.393153526970953182e-01,9.382780082987551840e-01,9.372406639004148277e-01,9.356846473029045708e-01,9.346473029045642145e-01,9.330912863070539576e-01,9.320539419087136013e-01,9.304979253112033444e-01,9.289419087136928654e-01,9.273858921161826085e-01,9.258298755186721296e-01,9.242738589211617617e-01,9.227178423236513938e-01,9.211618257261410259e-01,9.196058091286306579e-01,9.180497925311202900e-01,9.159751037344397995e-01,9.144190871369294316e-01,9.123443983402489410e-01,9.107883817427384621e-01,9.087136929460579715e-01,9.071576763485477146e-01,9.050829875518671130e-01,9.030082987551866225e-01,9.009336099585061319e-01,8.988589211618257524e-01,8.967842323651451508e-01,8.947095435684646603e-01,8.926348547717841697e-01,8.905601659751035681e-01,8.884854771784231886e-01,8.864107883817426980e-01,8.843360995850622075e-01,8.817427385892115943e-01,8.796680497925309927e-01,8.775933609958505022e-01,8.749999999999998890e-01,8.729253112033195094e-01,8.708506224066390189e-01,8.682572614107884057e-01,8.661825726141078041e-01,8.635892116182571909e-01,8.615145228215767004e-01,8.589211618257260872e-01,8.563278008298754740e-01,8.542531120331948724e-01,8.516597510373442592e-01,8.490663900414936460e-01,8.469917012448132665e-01,8.443983402489626533e-01,8.418049792531120401e-01,8.397302904564315496e-01,8.371369294605809364e-01,8.345435684647303232e-01,8.324688796680497216e-01,8.298755186721991084e-01,8.272821576763484952e-01,8.246887966804978820e-01,8.226141078838173915e-01,8.200207468879667783e-01,8.174273858921160540e-01,8.153526970954355635e-01,8.127593360995849503e-01,8.101659751037343371e-01,8.075726141078837239e-01,8.054979253112033444e-01,8.029045643153527312e-01,8.003112033195021180e-01,7.977178423236515048e-01,7.956431535269707922e-01,7.930497925311201790e-01,7.904564315352695658e-01,7.883817427385891863e-01,7.857883817427385731e-01,7.831950207468879599e-01,7.811203319502073583e-01,7.785269709543567451e-01,7.759336099585061319e-01,7.738589211618256414e-01,7.712655601659750282e-01,7.686721991701244150e-01,7.665975103734440355e-01,7.640041493775934223e-01,7.619294605809127097e-01,7.593360995850620965e-01,7.567427385892114833e-01,7.546680497925311037e-01,7.520746887966804906e-01,7.499999999999998890e-01,7.474066390041492758e-01,7.453319502074687852e-01,7.427385892116181720e-01,7.406639004149377925e-01,7.380705394190871793e-01,7.359958506224064667e-01,7.339211618257260872e-01,7.313278008298754740e-01,7.292531120331949834e-01,7.266597510373443702e-01,7.245850622406637687e-01,7.225103734439833891e-01,7.199170124481327759e-01,7.178423236514521744e-01,7.157676348547717948e-01,7.136929460580911933e-01,7.110995850622405801e-01,7.090248962655600895e-01,7.069502074688797100e-01,7.048755186721989974e-01,7.022821576763483842e-01,7.002074688796680046e-01,6.981327800829875141e-01,6.960580912863069125e-01,6.939834024896265330e-01,6.919087136929459314e-01,6.898340248962655519e-01,6.877593360995849503e-01])
cycles = np.arange(0,151)


#%% fit the capacity data

# define the empicrial model to be fitted
def He_model(k,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.exp(b*k)+c*np.exp(d*k)

# Fit the entire data set with the function
P0 = [-40,0.005,40,-0.005]
fit, tmp = sp.optimize.curve_fit(He_model, cycles,capacity, p0=P0,maxfev=10000000)
capacity_fit = He_model(cycles, fit[0], fit[1],fit[2], fit[3])


# track all four data points with a 5% bound from the best fit
b_lim = np.zeros((4,2))
for i in range(4):
    b_lim[i,0] = fit[i]-np.abs(0.2*fit[i]) # these should be 0.05
    b_lim[i,1] = fit[i]+np.abs(0.2*fit[i])

# bounds that work    
B  = ([b_lim[0,0],-np.inf,b_lim[2,0],-np.inf],[b_lim[0,1], np.inf, b_lim[2,1], np.inf])

# bounds that do not work, but are closer to what I want.
#B  = ([b_lim[0,0],b_lim[1,0],b_lim[2,0],b_lim[3,0]],[b_lim[0,1], b_lim[1,1], b_lim[2,1], b_lim[3,1]])


fit_4_5per, tmp = sp.optimize.curve_fit(He_model, cycles,capacity , p0=P0,bounds=B)
capacity_4_5per = He_model(cycles, fit_4_5per[0], fit_4_5per[1], fit_4_5per[2], fit_4_5per[3])

#%% plot the results

plt.figure()
plt.plot(cycles,capacity,'o',fillstyle='none',label='data',markersize=4)
plt.plot(cycles,capacity_fit,'--',label='best fit')
plt.plot(cycles,capacity_4_5per,'-.',label='5 percent bounds')
plt.ylabel('capacity')
plt.xlabel('charge cycles')
plt.legend()
plt.ylim([0.70,1])
plt.tight_layout()
```

I understand that optimize.curve_fit may need some space to explore the data set to find the optimum spot, however, I feel that 5% should be enough for it. Maybe I am wrong? Is there maybe a better way to apply bounds to a parameter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ValueError of "`x0` is infeasible" is coming because your initial values violate the bounds.  Printing out the parameters values and bounds will show this.

Basically, you're setting the bounds too cleverly, based on the first refined values.  But the refined values are different enough from your starting values that the bounds for the second call to `curve_fit` mean the initial values fall outside the bounds.

More importantly, what leads you to "feel that 5% should be enough"?  Primarily, you should apply bounds to make sure the model makes sense, and secondarily to help the fit avoid false solutions.   You're calculating the bounds based on an initial fit, so I doubt there's a strong physical justification for those bounds.  Why not let the fit do its job?

Comment: Thanks, changing my initial guess to the fitting parameters seems to have fixed the issue. A simple solution once you explained the problem to me. As per your second question, this MWE is part of a much larger code that is doing a much more complex task.  As presented here it does look odd, but I was just trying to express the problem in a simple manner.